# Groovy JSONArray : org.json.JSONException: when decoding string with \"

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I get no way to parse this Json which seems to be valid for me :

```
def diffOfApi='''[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/0/messageBody","value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<WCS reference=\"336042800000431486\"><PREPARATION_REQUEST requestId=\"WDP_PICKVRAC3\" date=\"2022-02-08 18:33:39\"><CONTAINERS><CONTAINER containerId=\"336042800000431486_21_21121\" handle=\"CREATE\" wmsOrderId=\"WDP_PICKVRAC3\" site=\"CPEEPF\" status=\"CREATED\" referenceDate=\"2022-02-08 18:33:39\" purgeAuthorized=\"false\"><BARCODES><BARCODE main=\"false\" reusable=\"false\">336042800000431486</BARCODE></BARCODES><PACKAGING>TX</PACKAGING><WEIGHT_CHECKING mode=\"NO\"/></CONTAINER></CONTAINERS></PREPARATION_REQUEST></WCS>"}]'''

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(diffOfApi);
```

I get this error :

```
Reason:
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 71 [character 72 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:229)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:363)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:115)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:144)
    at TEST.run(TEST:32)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:442)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:433)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:412)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:404)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:281)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:142)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:133)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1644483473725.run(TempTestCase1644483473725.groovy:25)
```

I think it is due to " encapsulated xml in item value

Any idea to make it working ?

Comment: Try to use jsonSlurper instead of jsonArray

Comment: @daggett the slurper complains about he same parse errors

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `\"` characters with `'` to allow for JSON- and later XML-processing:

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.json.*

def diffOfApi='''[{"op":"replace","path":"/data/0/messageBody","value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<WCS reference=\"336042800000431486\"><PREPARATION_REQUEST requestId=\"WDP_PICKVRAC3\" date=\"2022-02-08 18:33:39\"><CONTAINERS><CONTAINER containerId=\"336042800000431486_21_21121\" handle=\"CREATE\" wmsOrderId=\"WDP_PICKVRAC3\" site=\"CPEEPF\" status=\"CREATED\" referenceDate=\"2022-02-08 18:33:39\" purgeAuthorized=\"false\"><BARCODES><BARCODE main=\"false\" reusable=\"false\">336042800000431486</BARCODE></BARCODES><PACKAGING>TX</PACKAGING><WEIGHT_CHECKING mode=\"NO\"/></CONTAINER></CONTAINERS></PREPARATION_REQUEST></WCS>"}]'''

diffOfApi = diffOfApi.replaceAll( /=.{1}([^"]+)"/, "='\$1'" )

def jsonArray = new JsonSlurper().parseText diffOfApi

assert 3 == jsonArray.first().size()

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText jsonArray.first().value // root element points to <WCS/>

assert 'WDP_PICKVRAC3' == xml.PREPARATION_REQUEST.@requestId.text()
```

Comment: Not sure to well understand your regex, but it works well :) I would have prefered to not modify xml but it is suffisant for me ; thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

you have incorrectly encoded json string.

if json contains doublequote in a value `"` - it must be encoded as `\"` but inside the groovy/java code each `\` also must be encoded with `\\`

---

so when you have following in code:

```
def x = '''{"x":"abc\"def"}'''
```

then actual `x` value at runtime would be

```js
{"x":"abc"def"}
```

that is incorrect json

so, `x` should be defined as

```
def x = '''{"x":"abc\\"def"}'''
```

to have runtime value

```js
{"x":"abc\"def"}
```

Comment: as in my real case, I got a String directly by API, I cannot encode \ with \\ as they are already like that in apiReply.getResponseText()

Comment: Then show what in response of your API and how you are parsing it...